# While adding images in between the <a> the carousel stops working

Tags: html, jquery

#6 image carousel not working while adding  While adding images in between the  the carousel stops working. #

```
<div id="display-panel">
                <img src="images/left.jpg" class="prev" alt="">
                <div class="display-panel-inner">
                    <a href="newpage.html" class="abc"><img src="images/book1.jpg" alt="" class="active"></a>
                    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/book2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/book3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/book5.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/book6.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/book7.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <img src="images/right.jpg" class="next" alt="">
            </div>
```

#jquery for the above code is not working for the  tag i did some changes as well they are also not working #

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.next').on('click', () => {

        var isImg = $('.abc');
        var a = isImg.next('');
        console.log(a);
        var currentImg = $('.active');
        var nextImg = currentImg.next('.active');
        console.log(nextImg);
        if (nextImg.length) {
            currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
            nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('.prev').on('click', () => {
            var currentImg = $('.active');
            var prevImg = currentImg.prev();
            if (prevImg.length) {
                currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
                prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `**var nextImg` looks like a typo. What are the two asterisks for? Are you getting any errors in the console? Also, "not working" and "stops working" are not very helpful descriptions of the problem. What symptoms do you see? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73044689/edit) to be more descriptive.

Comment: Why do you never change the abc class?

Comment: There is no need to have more than one `$(document).ready()`, and you definitely should not nest one inside another.

Comment: This is just a test code that's why the weird class names.